# How does one install armory on ubuntu?

Tags: hp, chromebook, crouton

I downloaded armory (v 0.93.2) and tried to install it using "sudo pdkg -i," "wep," etc., but it will not run. I've also downloaded and installed the plug-ins for the preceding version of armory, but to no avail. The output when I attempt a terminal install is "cannot access archive; no such file or directory." Also, I'm running ubuntu on a chromebook using crouton.